# How to move a file back into the conflict state after conflict resolution?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I have a real bugger of a conflict resolution set, and I figured that I'd just go for it and if I failed, then I should be able to bring back the file into its conflict state.  However, I can't seem to find a way to go back.  git is still in MERGING state, so how do I backup a single file and reresolve?

Comment: Did you pushed your file to your branch before pulling?

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR, Not sure what you mean.  I have a lot of modifications to the file set.  I did a `git merge branch_name`. Then I did a `git mergetool`.  Now I want to undo a particular file.  Am I going to have to do a hard reset to that file and remerge?  Not even sure if that's possible to do on a single file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you think you might have a decent resolution (or part of it), copy the file somewhere else. :-) Then just run:

`git checkout -m -- path`

(the `--` part is needed only if the file's *`path`* resembles a valid `git checkout` option, e.g., if the file you want to put back in conflicted state is named `--theirs` or `-f` or some such).  This will re-create the conflict-marker variant of the file from the three inputs (merge base and both branch heads), and write that file to the work-tree.

Note that you can specify the `--conflict=merge` (default) style, or the `--conflict=diff3` style.  This is the same as setting `merge.conflictStyle` in `.gitconfig`, but just for that one file and this one checkout.

If you (or `git mergetool`) used a merge tool that already ran `git add` on the resolved variant, note that this puts the file back into conflicted state, i.e., it restores the three higher stage entries into the index.  You can now run `git mergetool` again, or—my personal preference—just manually edit the conflicted file and `git add` the resulting work-tree copy once you are satisfied that it is correct.

Comment: It was the `git checkout -m -- path` that was the piece of the puzzle I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: Hm. You should only get this by running either `git merge` or `git pull`, not by running `git checkout -m`.

Comment: Yeah, edited a line in the command line history.  Didn't see the `merge` command.

Comment: After `git checkout -m upstream/save -- README.md` as a single test file, `git mergetool` returns "No files need merging" :( while `git diff HEAD` shows the changes, some unwanted.  How can I force the mergetool GUI to run, allowing me to selectively choose edits from either B or C side? (A being _base_)

Comment: @Marcos: `git checkout -m` behaves differently if you're not still in a merge, vs if you are. If you *are* still in an incomplete merge—i.e., you haven't concluded th merge with `git commit` or `git merge --continue`—you would run `git checkout -m -- README.md` to restore it to unmerged state. I'm not sure what happens if you name a commit as well.