# force put a single file into conflicted merge state

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

An upstream branch (not master/default HEAD, if that matters) has a few updates I want, most other differences I don't.

First, I did `git fetch -v upstream` rather than `pull` since I don't want my local code (in my master branch) modified yet.

Doing `git merge upstream/nonmaster` would auto-merge lots of stuff I definitely do not want, removing many local files that never went upstream from my fork (because it's a different author/side project), etc.

Question, how can I get it to a state where `git mergetool` would launch my configured GUI (**kdiff3**)  to allow me to choose which edits to keep from panels A(base)/B(mine)/C(theirs) in all changed files (some altogether missing in the upstream, but I definitely want to keep in my branch)?

Currently it returns "No files need merging", although `git diff HEAD` shows the differences, which evidently it would auto-merge.  I don't want automatic; I want to choose what gets merged/changed, in most cases keeping my stuff the way it was.

I am okay with doing it one single file at a time...how please?
Say, `git checkout -m upstream/save -- README.md` as a test file.

Several sources including a (related issue)[[How to move a file back into the conflict state after conflict resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217712/how-to-move-a-file-back-into-the-conflict-state-after-conflict-resolution]) refer to variants of `git checkout -m ...`

However, still I face *"No files need merging"* and the conflict resolution is not forced after all, while `git diff HEAD` shows auto-merged changes I would mostly not want.

````
 git status; git diff HEAD

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   README.md


diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 9a7e6a0..1be114b 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -21,22 +21,23 @@ Setup


-Before you begin, make sure you have `Python3` installed. Robinhood shell only works with python3. Some of the functionality is broken on python2.7 
+Download Robinhood Shell by downloading the zip file ([link](https://github.com/ploch/RobinhoodShell/archive/dev.zip)) OR by using git 

-1. Download Robinhood Shell by downloading the zip file ([link](https://github.com/anilshanbhag/RobinhoodShell/archive/dev.zip)) OR by using git 
+=======

 ```
-git clone https://github.com/anilshanbhag/RobinhoodShell.git
+git clone https://github.com/ploch/RobinhoodShell.git
````

COROLLARY (possibly?)

How in the git piping can we manually make *conflict markers*, where otherwise `git merge` would think it's done its job automatically?

Comment: I'd suggest `git pull --rebase=interactive` (`--rebase=i` since git 2.19)

Comment: `--no-ff --no-commit` to manually stage changes. But this _applys_ them and wouldn't affect mergetool behavior.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657009/how-to-merge-all-files-manually-in-git